# PythonAnywhere Scheduled Tasks Virtualenv - No Results

Tags: python, virtualenv, pythonanywhere

I am trying to schedule an hourly task with python anywhere inside a virtualenv.  I can run the script successfully in the bash console.  However the scheduled task does not seem to produce the same result. Or do anything for that matter.

For reference, the script parses a google spreadsheet to geocode a series of addresses.

[image]

Here are the bash console steps that work to produce the results in the image above.

1. Upload quickstart.py to pythonanywhere inside project folder called
   'lovelytics'.
2. Inside project folder (lovelytics) open bash console.
3. Initiate virtual environment for python 2.7.

   *mkvirtualenv myvenv --python=python2.7*
4. Install dependencies inside myvenv.

   *pip install gspread oauth2client geopy*
5. Run the script.

   *python quickstart.py*

However, when I try to run the same script using scheduled tasks nothing happens.  Here is what I have tried there...

[image]

The code appears to run at the time scheduled.

[image]

But no results in the spreadsheet.

[image]

Why does this not produce the same results as the bash console?

**Edit** (adding log details):

> File "/home/remmi11/lovelytics/quickstart.py", line 13, in  ..
>   IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'client_secret.json'

Line 13 in quickstart.py is this...

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)

But the file resides within the lovelytics directory?
[image]

Comment: What do you mean "nothing happens"? What are you expecting to happen? Your scheduled task log will show whether the task has run and also include any output from the task.

Comment: Sorry @Glenn I have edited the question for clarity.  What I mean is that although the scheduled process initiates I do not get the desired results in the spreadsheet like I do the bash console.  I think I am not configuring the scheduled task correctly.  But am not sure what is missing?

Comment: And your task log? If there are any errors, they'll be there

Comment: Good call.  Msg is 'No such file..' but the file resides alongside the script? See edits.

Comment: Thanks for the direction @glenn. It seems the file needed an absolute path to '/home/remmi11/lovelytics/client_secret.json'.  With this change the script works